# Comparing of Date objects in Java

Tags: java, date, equals, compareto

I recently observed an oddity, when comparing two Java Date objects with equals(). Please note that both, this.getDate() and other.getDate(), will return a Java Date object in my application.

**Code:**

```
logger.debug("Date 1: " + this.getDate().toString());
logger.debug("Date 1: " + this.getDate().getTime());

logger.debug("Date 2: " + other.getDate().toString());
logger.debug("Date 2: " + other.getDate().getTime());

logger.debug("Dates are equal: " + this.getDate().equals(other.getDate()));
logger.debug("Dates match in comparison: " + (this.getDate().compareTo(other.getDate()) == 0));
```

**Output:** (added blank lines for better readability)

```
Date 1: 2014-07-28 00:00:00.0
Date 1: 1406498400000

Date 2: Mon Jul 28 00:00:00 CEST 2014
Date 2: 1406498400000

Dates are equal: false
Dates match in comparison: true
```

There are two things I don't get:

1. Why does equals() return false?
2. Why does the return value of toString() change its format?

I checked the documentation of [Date.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) where it says:

> Compares two dates for equality. The result is true if and only if the
>   argument is not null and is a Date object that represents the same
>   point in time, to the millisecond, as this object.
>
> **Thus, two Date objects are equal if and only if the getTime method
>   returns the same long value for both**.

I also had a look at the implementation of Date.equals():

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
}
```

So why does `equals()` return **false**, even though `getTime()` returns **1406498400000** for both `Date` objects?

Reference:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Although I don't know why equals() returns false, you can always switch and use [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) to compare the Dates (a method I have yet to see fail!)

Comment: toString does not change the format, Date has no concept of format, it's just a container of the number of milliseconds. The toString ,ethos simple uses the current local to display a representation of the this value.

Comment: Can you update your example to include the construction of the `Date()` objects?

Comment: because .equals() compares objects and .compare() compares strings

Comment: @A.O. Based on the rest of the code, that's what the OP is doing (getDate is returning the Date object)

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya No, I don't think so. compareTo and equals are free to use what ever means they feel are best to produce there result

Comment: Perhaps your `getDate` method is not doing what it would be expected to do. I think we should see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess they are not both Date objects as the formatting is different.

java.sql.Timestamp extends java.util.Date but it is a different class and is not equal.

From Timestamp

```
public boolean equals(java.lang.Object ts) {
  if (ts instanceof Timestamp) {
    return this.equals((Timestamp)ts);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You might find that if you compare them the other way around it returns true. :P

try

```
logger.debug("Dates are equal: " + other.getDate().equals(this.getDate()));
```

Comment: This is probably the reason. Seeing the docs of the `toString()` method of each class, `this.getDate()` probably returns a `java.util.Date`, while `other.getDate()` is returning `java.sql.Date`

Comment: Thanks Peter, you nailed it! Date 1 was instanceof `java.sql.Timestamp` (and instanceof `java.util.Date`). Date 2 was instanceof `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

From the toString output

It is clear that Date1 is object of the class java.sql.Date 
and Date2 is object of java.util.Date

So  the toString output is different and the equals() method is giving false.

Because  (obj instanceof Date) will return false.

Comment: Ah, no, `java.sql.Date` is an instance of (`instanceof`) `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date` extends from `java.util.Date`. In fact, the only comparison that fails is `Timestamp#equals(Date)` because the object been matched isn't an instance of `Timestamp`...